# Tree Like Query On SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, tree, recursive-query

i have a query join 4 tables

```
SELECT
a.Id AS KelompokInformasi, d.Name AS Domain, d.Id AS Dimension, e.Text AS Description FROM XBRLNamespaces a
INNER JOIN Hypercubes b
ON a.XBRLView_ViewId = b.XBRLView_ViewId
INNER JOIN HypercubeDimensionItems c
ON b.XBRLHypercubeId = c.XBRLHypercube_XBRLHypercubeId
INNER JOIN Items d
ON c.XBRLItem_ItemId = d.ItemId
INNER JOIN Labels e
ON d.ItemId = e.XBRLItem_ItemId
WHERE a.Id like '%AAKX%'
```

the query result is

```
KelompokInformasi   Domain  Dimension   Description
AAKX            JWAAKT  dim_JWAAKT  Jangka Waktu Aset
AAKX            KOKOLT  dim_KOKOLT  Kolektibilitas
AAKX            SNOUPL  dim_SNOUPL  Status Operasional Usaha Pihak Lawan
```

AAKX is a parent from the other data in Domain, Dimension, and Description.

So, i want to change the query and in the end have an output query result like this:

```
KelompokInformasi   Domain  Dimension   Description
AAKX            NULL    NULL        NULL
NULL            JWAAKT  dim_JWAAKT  Jangka Waktu Aset
NULL            KOKOLT  dim_KOKOLT  Kolektibilitas
NULL            SNOUPL  dim_SNOUPL  Status Operasional Usaha Pihak Lawan
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you must use Group by with cube and having. Or grouping sets.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522495(v=SQL.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
'KelompokInformasi' = 
  CASE
    WHEN a.Id like '%AAKX%' THEN a.Id
    ELSE NULL
  END, 
'Domain' =
  CASE
    WHEN a.Id like '%AAKX%' THEN NULL
    ELSE d.Name
  END, 
'Dimension' =
  CASE
    WHEN a.Id like '%AAKX%' THEN NULL
    ELSE d.Id
  END,
'Description' =
  CASE
    WHEN a.Id like '%AAKX%' THEN NULL
    ELSE e.Text
  END,
FROM XBRLNamespaces a
INNER JOIN Hypercubes b
ON a.XBRLView_ViewId = b.XBRLView_ViewId
INNER JOIN HypercubeDimensionItems c
ON b.XBRLHypercubeId = c.XBRLHypercube_XBRLHypercubeId
INNER JOIN Items d
ON c.XBRLItem_ItemId = d.ItemId
INNER JOIN Labels e
ON d.ItemId = e.XBRLItem_ItemId
WHERE a.Id like '%AAKX%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Common table Expression(CTE),ROW_NUMBER() and Same Case statement used as above:

WITH **cte** AS 
SELECT 
a.Id AS KelompokInformasi,d.Name AS DOMAIN,d.Id AS Dimension,e.Text AS Description ,
**ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.Id ORDER BY a.ID) AS COL5**
FROM XBRLNamespaces a
INNER JOIN Hypercubes b 
ON a.XBRLView_ViewId = b.XBRLView_ViewId
INNER JOIN HypercubeDimensionItems c 
ON b.XBRLHypercubeId = c.XBRLHypercube_XBRLHypercubeId
INNER JOIN Items d 
ON c.XBRLItem_ItemId = d.ItemId
INNER JOIN Labels e 
ON d.ItemId = e.XBRLItem_ItemId
WHERE a.Id LIKE '%AAKX%' )
SELECT **CASE**
         WHEN COL5 >1 THEN NULL ELSE KelompokInformasi END AS KelompokInformasi,
       **CASE**
         WHEN COL5=1 THEN NULL ELSE DOMAIN END AS DOMAIN,
       **CASE**
         WHEN COL5=1 THEN NULL ELSE Dimension END AS Dimension,
       **CASE**
         WHEN COL5=1 THEN NULL ELSE Description END AS Description
FROM **cte**

Comment: yep, this query is almost correct but i lost the last line of my result, what wrong could it be?

Comment: Analyse it again and again may be you get the answer..can u just elaborate the question,not understanding what last part of ur result..